# How to install puppet-enterprise on fedora 19?

Tags: installation, fedora, puppet

Can some one help me with it, i found in docs of puppet-EE that fedora is supported OS but I cant install any kind of tarballs. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora is not on [the supported list of Puppet Enterprise operating systems](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/install_system_requirements.html#operating-system). If you want a Red Hat based OS, and don't want to use RHEL you can use CentOS.